# PHP: how to convert SQL result in csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I'm trying to convert an SQL query result in a CSV File but I can't find a working solution. Do you have any suggestion?

Tnx in advance!

Here is my code:

```
 <? mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");  

                $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM richieste GROUP BY mail");
while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 ) )

            {

            $id="{$row2['id']}";
            $nominativo="{$row2['nominativo']}";
            $mail="{$row2['mail']}";
            $telefono="{$row2['telefono']}";
            $comune="{$row2['comune']}";
            $cap="{$row2['cap']}";
            $provincia="{$row2['provincia']}";
            $regione="{$row2['regione']}";


            echo"
            <tr><td width='20%' align='left' class='testo_verde_maiuscolo'><a href='visualizza_richieste.php?mail=$mail&id=$id'>$nominativo</a></td><td width='15%' align='left' class='testo_verde'><a href='mailto:$mail'>$mail</a></td>
            <td width='10%' align='left' class='testo_verde'>$telefono</td><td width='15%' align='left' class='testo_verde'>";
```

Looking for a value in another table

```
            $result_comune = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comuni WHERE cod_istat=$comune");
while( $row_comune = mysql_fetch_array( $result_comune ) )
            { $comune_traslata="{$row_comune['comune']}";echo"$comune_traslata";
            }
            echo"</td><td width='10%' align='left' class='testo_verde'>
            $cap</td><td width='10%' align='left' class='testo_verde'>
    ";
```

here I'm looking for the value in another table

```
        $result_provincia = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM province WHERE cod_provincia=$provincia");
while( $row_provincia = mysql_fetch_array( $result_provincia ) )
            {

            $provincia_traslata="{$row_provincia['provincia']}";
            echo"$provincia_traslata";
            }
            echo"</td>
            <td align='left' class='testo_verde'>";
```

same as before, looking for the value in another table

```
            $result_regione = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regioni WHERE cod_regione=$regione");
while( $row_regione = mysql_fetch_array( $result_regione ) )
            {

            $regione_traslata="{$row_regione['regione']}";

        echo"$regione_traslata";
            }
            echo"</td>
            ";  
            echo"</tr>";
```

First edit: tryed with this code:

```
$_csv_data="id;nominativo;mail;telefono\n";
@fwrite( $_fp, $_csv_data);
while (list( $id, $nominativo, $mail, $telefono) = mysql_fetch_row($result3))
{
$_csv_data = $id.';'.$nominativo.';'.$mail.';'.$telefono."\n";
@fwrite( $_fp, $_csv_data);
}
@fclose( $_fp );
```

but I'm getting just the firs line of the csv.

```
} ?>
```

Comment: is exporting as csv from phpmyadmin not an option?

Comment: *"I'm trying to convert an SQL query result in a CSV File but I can't find a working solution."* - I find that rather hard to believe. Google "convert SQL result in csv mysql php" plenty of results.

Comment: whats with the different code snippets? if you can write html with your results, you can write csv.

Comment: By the way; all of your `where` clauses look like they're strings and those variables need to be wrapped in quotes. I.e.: `WHERE cod_provincia='$provincia'");`. Using `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` would have triggered an syntax error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- tnx for your suggestion about using quotes, I'm almos a newbie in PHP - MYsql and trying to learn more. I used this:  `$_csv_data="id;nominativo;mail;telefono\n";
@fwrite( $_fp, $_csv_data);
while (list( $id, $nominativo, $mail, $telefono) = mysql_fetch_row($result3))
{
$_csv_data = $id.';'.$nominativo.';'.$mail.';'.$telefono."\n";
@fwrite( $_fp, $_csv_data);
}
@fclose( $_fp );`   but I just get the first line of csv, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeated `mysql_fetch_array` calls in the HTML generating `while` loop will consume all of the rows, leaving the internal result pointer at the end when finished. Therefore, when you try another `mysql_fetch_array` on the same result, already being at the end of the result, you will not receive any (more) rows.

Try adding a ...

```
mysql_data_seek($result3, 0);
```

... before the second/CSV generating loop, to move the internal pointer to the start of the query result.

As a side note, please see this from [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) on `mysql_*` function usage:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used [...]

Comment: Tnx for your kind help! I'll try it immediatly!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you note trying writing the data into your csv file directly from MySQL(you can use **into outfile**).
Below is an example:

```
SELECT * FROM province WHERE cod_provincia=$provincia into outfile '/tmp/abc.csv' fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Based on the where clause in query, data will be written in csv file.

Comment: Tnx a lot for your kind reply! I didn't know about this function. I'll take immediatly a look and will try to get it working. I'll let you know, tnx again!

Comment: using this you can avoid all that coding part in php.